# microsoft azure client swift library select with nolock

Tags: ios, sql, swift, xcode, azure

Using Azure client APIs for Swift, and have the following code:

```
let userTable = azureClient!.table(withName: TABLE_USER)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "fbid==\"\(fbid)\"")
userTable.query(with: predicate).read(completion: completion)
```

This works with no issues, however I like to know how to use the API in order for it to use `with (nolock)` option when doing running the`select` SQL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to instead using Easy API and calling the API, where you can specify the SQL, eg. "select * from with (nolock) tablename"